# Suggestions for drawing a complex hierarchy at multiple sizes

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I am trying to think of a way to render a sub-hierarchy that is somewhat complex, and would look good (crisp) when drawn at multiple scales.

I would expect there to be some container view with a size, and this subview could be constrained within it and drawn properly.

If it helps think of a hierarchy like a calculator keypad or computer keyboard even:

[image: keypad 1]

[image: keypad 2]

You would have a keyContainer view, and a bunch of key views (or layers) of various sizes and positions.

Suppose I wanted this to be drawn in a container that was 320 x 320. I was thinking if I knew the ratio of w:h for each key and I knew the ratio of a key's width to the width of the whole container, then I could work out the sizes and positions for the key. I've found in practice the math seems to introduce a lot of rounding errors and you end up on off-pixel boundaries so the final rendering does not look great.

So how would you tackle a problem like this?

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: It appears that all of your subviews have the same height (or at least, the same height within each row). Is that true in general? If so, you can do these layouts pretty easily with `UIStackView`. If not, you can do it manually with constraints (but it's pretty tedious) or you can do the math yourself (which as you've discovered is not trivial).

Comment: A stack view is an interesting idea. I think it might corner me though as soon as I need an item that is not the same height as the others in a row (something I foresee happening).